# Law of Contrapositives?

Tags: logic, argumentation, knowledge

The *Law of Contrapositives* states that if a conditional statement is true, then it's contrapositive will also be true. I can easily see this works through example conditional statements, but why does this work?

**For example**:

The contrapositive of

```
"If it is raining then the grass is wet"
```

is

```
"If the grass is not wet then it is not raining."
```

Both are interpreted true.

Comment: You can easily check with truth table that **A → B** is equivalent to **~B → ~A**.

Comment: If the grass isn't wet, then it can't be raining, because if it *were* raining, the grass *would* be wet. This is the basic principle behind [weather rocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weather_rock).

Answer (score 2):

Conditional statements are closely related to disjunctive statements. Using logical notation, this can be written as:

> A → B ⇔ ~A ∨ B

Given this relation, the first statement can be interpreted as asserting one of two things:

> It is not raining.

or

> The grass is wet.

Since the second statement asserts that if the grass is not wet, eliminating the second possibility, the first will be true: It is not raining.